# magento 2.1.0 when i am save admin panel email template. page geting error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database

> admin panel > marketing > Email template > add new emailtemplate > select template

If the selected template contains a href link the page returns an error, how can I solve this? Example:

```
<a href="{{var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword',[_query:[id:$customer.id,token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}" target="_blank">{{trans "Set a New Password"}}</a> '}}

{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p class="greeting">{{trans "%name," name=$customer.name}}</p>
<p>{{trans "There was recently a request to change the password for your account."}}</p>
<p>{{trans "If you requested this change, set a new password here:"}}</p>

<table class="button" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="inner-wrapper" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">
                        <a href="{{var this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/createPassword',[_query:[id:$customer.id,token:$customer.rp_token],_nosid:1])}}" target="_blank">{{trans "Set a New Password"}}</a> '}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<p>{{trans "If you did not make this request, you can ignore this email and your password will remain the same."}}</p>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is may be cause by mode security, just contact to your hosting  company and tell them about this error and they will allow you permission to save this page.

Hope it will help you:)

Answer (score 0):

give the file permision of email template. and rune this command

```
Run following command php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
Run php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Run php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Run php bin/magento cache:clean
```